# Android app using beacons to get informations

Tags: android, beacon

I'm new with programming in Android using Beacons. 
There is situation that i have to create: When you are comming to the doors (beacon is there) the App should show you some informations. I don't have any plan for it and i don't know how to start. 
Can anyone help me?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You can use the BeaconManager for getting the information about all the beacons around. It provides you UUID and other related data corresponding to each beacon.

For reference, you can refer to this link:
https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

The beacons come in your range under the region while discovering you can get the list in its override method.

```
private void startRangingBeaconsInRegion() throws RemoteException {

  beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
      @Override
      public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
          if(beacons == null || beacons.isEmpty()) {
              Log.d("DEBUG", "No beacons");
          } else {
              EstimoteBeacons.this.beacons = beacons;
              Beacon mClosetBeacon=beacons.get(0);
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: I want to use many beacons but i wanna get informations only from one of them (the closest). I couldn't find any good code for my problem there in your link (it works only for 1 beacon). Should I create some List of Major and Minors? Or there is another way to solve it?

Comment: "EstimoteBeacons.this.beacons = beacons;" got some problems with it ("EstimoteBeacons is not an enclosing class").

Comment: Its my Activity Class name ,as we are getting the context of class in other anonymous class.its not a any library class.

Comment: Ok, got it. But I have to get different notification for every Beacon I use. For example I have 2 beacons (Green and Blue). I want to get notifiaction "I'm green" or "I'm blue" when I'm close to one of these beacons. My code is working for one beacon only, but i have to make it for more than one

Comment: Hi! Check the above code updated for your answer once we get the beacon on enter while monitoring we send the notification.but we have to save action of each corresponding  beacon with their UUID in database based on that we can change the action for each beacons